# Java script not being executed (at all) by I.E. or Firefox but Chrome has no issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

So I just finished writing a fairy large ammount of javascript only to discover that what I saw in Chrome is being ignored by both Firefox and i.e. 8 (based on our statistics this is the target browser). The code is as follows:

```
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/jscript" language="javascript" >

   alert("here");
    $(window).load(function () {

        $('div#pop-up').hide();
        $('div#pop-up-side').hide();
   ....
```

I put in

```
   alert("here");
```

and quickly realized that the only browser that even GETS to alert("here") is Chrome. Any ideas on what may fix this? I am not sure what else to provide you, let me know.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe that `type="text/jscript"` is causing other browsers to trash the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the right type (not `text/jscript` but `text/javascript`) will help in Firefox.  No idea what you're seeing in IE...

Answer (score 1):

the `type` attribute is optional and defaults to `text/javascript` if absent. The `language` attribute is ignored by browsers. You may omit both.

Also, it's better off you use `.ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("here");
    $('div#pop-up').hide();
    $('div#pop-up-side').hide();
    ...
```

And check the console for errors.

Comment: Already ran into this problem earlier. I'm using ASP.NET + EXT.NET which means that $(document).ready fires before the page even renders.